# $ARGV[0] is not working in Solaris SPARC

Tags: perl

I used `$var=$ARGV[0]` in some Perl code on a Solaris x64 machine and it is receiving the argument correctly.
But the same piece of code is not working in Solaris SPARC.
Any clue?

Also `$_[0`] is working in Solaris SPARC, but then it is not working in Solaris x64.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Show the command you ran, and the output you got.

Comment: What are you expecting in `$ARGV[0]`?  What are you getting?  Justify your expectation (show the command line you're running).  Which version of Solaris on each platform?  Which version of Perl (typically, it is not the current 5.18.x version)?  As for `$_[0]`, you'll have to provide a lot more context to justify how it is or is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Try this program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print join ": ", @ARGV . "\n";
```

Run it with a bunch of command line arguments, and tell me what you're getting as an output. It should look something like this:

```
$ myprog.pl one two three four five
one: two: three: four: five
```

Next, try the same thing with this program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print join ": ", @ARGV . "\n";
my $value = $ARGV[0];
print qq(My value = "$value"\n);
```

Now, edit your question to show us the output you're getting. This way, we'll know what you mean. Also, give us at least a code snippet of what is not working, what you expect, and what you're getting.

Writing a quick etest program is always a good way to track down an issue, and can give you something to post on Stackoverflow if you're still stuck.

Comment: Missing `)` on line 5

Comment: `bash-3.2$ cat myprog.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;
print join ": ", @ARGV . "\n";
bash-3.2$ perl myprog.pl one two three
3`

Comment: It is returning no of arguments passed instead !!